# vba excel copy and paste date

Tags: excel, vba, date, formatting, copy-paste

maybe simple the solution but suffering from days.
I have an excel sheet with dates, if I check format of it shows Custom / TT.MMM .
This date I want to paste into another sheet but cannot even I checked different methods with pastespecial.
tried from simple xlpastevalues till xlpasteallusingsourcethemes, where all the result is only numbers.
closest result is 1900.01.00 in the sheet, if I check number format it shows Date but not the proper one like 2023.07.27 or something similar.
I tried to add an extra row with .numberformat "YYYY/MM/DD" or even with "-" or "." but doesnt change
My reginal setting is English (US) so as Ive read some articels on site I have to be okay but seems not:/

related part of my code is...pls help thx

```
wsGL.Range("J" & i).Copy
wsLCLHU.Range("G" & lastrowHU).Offset(1, 26).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Comment: TT.MMM is not a valid format?

Comment: Do you mean `dd.mmm`?  `Set r = wsLCLHU.Range("G" & lastrowHU).Offset(1, 26)   
sGL.Range("J" & i).Copy r   
r.NumberFormatLocal = "dd.mmm"`

Comment: Hello TIm TT.MMM is valid as meaning in German Tage Tage, Monate Monate Monate

Comment: Taller_ExcelHome tested and doesnt work. Maybe the problem that we use special "screen" via VPN with our company server. Setup is handled by central IT and maybe some settings are rather german than US. I mean I can see date in a format 2023.07.28. in right bottomo corner. Normal screen without VPN shows US date format 7/28/2023. BUt these setups I cannot modify as me is not admnistrator

Comment: Both thank you working now, but mistake on my end...I used wrong range in case copy from:/ Solved now and works in proper manner